# Email an SMS or SMS thread

Tags: gratis, android

I am looking for a free Android application that allows me to email a given SMS or SMS thread with my Gmail account. The email should be easily readable by a human (i.e. not wordy XML).

---

[Email My Texts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeesoftware.emailnytexts&hl=en) fits the requirements but isn't free.

[image]

[image]